# Shell script to generate war file recursively for multiple projects

Tags: java, linux, shell, war

I want to generate war file for multiple java projects in the same folder with folder name being the name of respective war file.

```
Folder Structure:
/home/admin/wars have files a , b , c ,d ,e 

I want to create war files a.war, b.war , c.war ,d.war , e.war
```

with a single shell command.

I know the command to create a single war file:

```
jar -cvf /home/admin/wars/a.war *
```

How to do this for multiple projects in the same folder with folder names being war name.?

Comment: have you thought about building your project(s) with a build tool? like maven?

Comment: I am doing this on jenkins via shell script.

Answer (score 1):

It's very great you use Jenkins.

Anyway, you should use a build tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), or [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/), which are totally supported in Jenkins.

For instance, check this [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin).

As asked in your comments, you can get further documentation:

- about [Jenkins plugins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-UsingcustombuildsofpluginsincludedintheJenkinsWAR)
- about [WAR Installation using Maven](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installation+via+Maven+WAR+Overlay)

Comment: I did try with jenkins plugins but i am not able to find a suitable reference for help for such case. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Yes, you can get additional documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-UsingcustombuildsofpluginsincludedintheJenkinsWAR), and [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installation+via+Maven+WAR+Overlay)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
cd /home/admin/wars
find ./ -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec jar -cvf {}.war {} \;

// maxdepth makes sure you don't go into subdirectories
```

(I didn't test this solution)

Comment: Thanks. Its giving error : javac: invalid flag: -cvf

Comment: @RahulAnand Sorry, I made a mistake, it should have been `jar` instead of `javac`, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks, It did run without error but didn't create war files.

Comment: You're right: I should not have put the directory reference in the output files. My answer has been updated again, now it seems to work (at least on my system).